# Why my child class doesn't inherit the font of parent class?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create menus for my website.

Overall, i have a big div that cover all of the children div inside. I set the big Div font-family to "A", some of the children do inherit that font, but the select box doesn't.

I have already found a fix: Add font-family to select element in my css, but i still don't understand why it doesn't inherit the parent font.
I am missing something?

My code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "text-control-view">
            <div>
                Previous Chapter <br> <br>
                <a href="#" class ="btn"> <span>CH #212</span> </a>
            </div>
            <div > 
                Available Chapter <br> <br>
                <select>
                    <option val=""><span>CH# 283<span></option>                 
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                Next Chapter <br> <br>
                <a href="#" class ="btn"> <span>CH #213</span> </a>
            </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.text-control-view{
    padding-top:10px;
  font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
    color:#4a5568;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
select{
    background:white;
    padding:3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:  1.5px solid gray;
    font-size:16px;
    color:black;
    
}

.btn {
        border: 1.5px solid gray;
        font-size:16px;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        background:white;
}
```

My Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k57tzrcj/2/

Can you guys help me clarify this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inputs don't inherit the font of it's parent by default. You need to add:

```
input, select, textarea, etc... {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
select{
    background:white;
    padding:3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:  1.5px solid gray;
    font-size:16px;
    color:black;
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

It will inherit from parent otherwise it will use browser default.